# create a digital archive with a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, asp.net, database

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to create a website with a database that will store all the files in the archive with the ability to delete files and upload new ones to the database from my web page.

1)I used HTML, CSS, javascript to create the website
2)MySQL to create the database 
and I also tried phpMyAdmin to create the database 
but where will I go from there?
How will my website control and show the database?

Comment: can you please share your code snippets

Comment: Look into frameworks like Angular, React, or Vue. Also, you don't store file data in a database, only the paths to the actual files.

Comment: what do you mean by the path to the actual files ? I need the database to store all my files

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I assume that you don't have a backend for your website. You need to have a backend to access the database. You can use php as the backend to connect with the mySQL database.

PS: I can see that you have tagged the question with php. If you are using php and still you can't connect to the database, please share your code snippets.

Comment: My website now is connected to the database and I was able to store usernames, passwords ... into the database. but how can I upload and store my files into the database? I need to insert the content of the file and then upload the file directly to the database ... Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: The better way to do it is, you upload files to a directory on the server and then save the path to the directory in the database.